# Android - Best way to store multiple layout variants

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

In my quiz application there are 3 quiz modes: 
multiple choice, single choice and fill-in-the-blank text.

Until now I implemented the layout for the multiple choice mode as below

[image]

Here I'm using checkboxes. For the single choice I will use radio buttons and for the fill-in-the-blank text text fields. 
I packed the checkboxes in a additonal linear layout inside my relative layout.
That means I only have to change this linear layout.

Should I create 3 inner linear layouts inside my layout file for the 3 modes (and make them invisible by default)? Or is there a better way to handle this.

Comment: I would use Fragments, you load the right fragment depending on the layout you need to use, so you can also have a controller for the answer the user gives

Comment: @LucaNicoletti But, they would use layouts too. I believe the OP is asking whats the best way to define those layouts

Comment: Relative layout, always the best one

Answer (score 3):

ViewStub might be what you are looking for.  You can include multiple layouts and only inflate the one you need.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should have a single layout file for the quiz screen layout and then to put the options section layout, the best option would be to define separate layout files containing only option elements for each question type something like:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <Checkbox/>
    <Checkbox/>
    <Checkbox/>
    <Checkbox/>
    <Checkbox/>
</LinearLayout>  // Similarly for other types
```

Then, add them to your parent `<RelativeLayout.../>` in quiz layout at runtime via `addView()`. In this way your quiz layout would be separate from changes in your options layout and can also accommodate adding more question types later if needed.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I put a placeholder for these quiz mode layouts in my quiz layout?

Comment: There are various ways to add layouts programmatically like @jt-gilkeson mentioned in another answer (using `ViewStubs`).